# jQuery submit form by clicking link issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to submit a form by clicking on a link. I disabled the redirection, but for some reason .submit() is not working...
Here is what I have tried:

Effect: redirection stops, no form submission, no error message, stuck on the form page:

```
$('.jsubmit').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form#fadmin').submit();
});
```

Effect: URL redirection, form not submitted, no error message

```
$('.jsubmit').click( function(e) {
    $('form#fadmin').submit();
});
```

Effect: redirection stops, no form submission, no error message, stuck on form page:

```
$('.jsubmit').click( function(e) {
    $('form#fadmin').submit();
    return false;
});
```

The form:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="fadmin" class="inputform" id="fadmin">...</form>
```

And a bunch of other combination including trigger(), reversing the preventDefault() with unbind(). The only way I was able to submit the form was to trigger a click on the submit button but that is not really a solution in my case, because I need to use this on multiple pages and adding the button then hiding it is not something I would like to do on every page...

I have tried to run them in Firefox and IE with the same result.

Some other JS, jQ codes being used are: default bootstrap and respond provided by ZendFramework2 and ZFTables.
Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

The form had the following submit button:

```
<input id="mysubmit" type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
```

After removing this my first example above worked perfectly.
Strange because there was no other forms or submit buttons on the page and nothing with the same name, id, type...

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors? Your first example should work.

Comment: What does just $('form#fadmin').submit(); do when you type it in console?

Comment: It works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65r8n3ed/1/).

Comment: Of course. As I said all combinations came up without any errors.

Comment: First mistake is you preventing click event of jsubmit input submit button ... but you actually want to prevent default action of form so... try this cde $("#fadmin").submit(function(event){event.preventDefault();....});

Comment: @Flas: The console response is: Object { 0: <form#fadmin.inputform>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → participanttest, selector: "form#fadmin" }

Comment: @kamesh why do you think default sumbit behaviour should be prevented? OP said nothing about custom form submit handling.

Comment: Your first piece of code should work, but your form element has no action. Where should it post?

Comment: @DariusVaughan-Scott: if there is no action defined than it is sent to the same URL. That is not a problem. But just to make sure I have tested it with defined action and the result is the same.

Comment: maybe u r clicking on the button that was created after page load. if so you can try with `on` selector http://api.jquery.com/on/ like this `$(document).on('click', '.jsubmit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form#fadmin').submit();
});`, or if u r using jquery < 1.7, try live http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you are trying to call submit() on a jQuery object, not the form DOM element.

Try this as your second line of code:

```
$('form#fadmin')[0].submit();
```