# jQuery submit method doesnt submit form data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to prevent submitting form on clicking if **amount is <10** and using jQuery AJAX to update amount after every 2 seconds. If meanwhile **amount > 10** then I want to re-submit the form which is already filled.

I have used

```
$("form").submit(function(e){ e.Preventdefault;})
```

To prevent submitting the form when **amount < 10** and if meanwhile amount updates to **> 10** then I am unbinding the submit button and calling submit function again.

```
$("form").unbind("submit");
$("form").submit();
```

But this doesnt POST the data to action URL.

Here's my complete code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var damount;
    var checking=0;
    setInterval(Call2, 3000);
    function Call2() {
        damount=$("#damount").val();
        if(damount>10 && checking==1)
        {
            $("form").unbind('submit');
            $("form").submit();

        }
    }

    $("#addproject").click(function(){
        checking=1;
        damount=$("#damount").val();
        if(damount<10)
        {
            $("form").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        } 
    });
```

Comment: Something is not quite right with your code structure. Put your code in jsfiddle or similar. We''ll take it from there.

Comment: Hi carlodurso here's code structure http://pastebin.com/e0wjb5BJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See another similar post and my response here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25806502/4021932

You're trying to call submit() on a jQuery object, which won't work. You need to call it on the DOM element.

```
$("form").unbind('submit'); //This is fine as it's dealing with the submit event, which jQuery handles
$("form")[0].submit(); //This calls submit() on the form DOM element
```

---

What about trying something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        var damount = parseInt($("#damount").val());
        if (damount < 10) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        $("form")[0].submit();
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Hi Tried this but not working. Please check this code http://pastebin.com/e0wjb5BJ

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to register an event handler based on a condition that can change, which requires you to deregister the handler (as in your unbind example) when the condition changes. Why don't you try putting the condition inside your event handler function instead, so it will only post when the amount is > 10? Then you can call submit() on the form DOM element periodically and the form will only post when the right condition is met.

Comment: I am getting error in console TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function

Comment: Thanks Darius .. I had some problem in PHP but your code was working fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: And i have used this code in two pages. in one page its working fine but in another its giving error. TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function. Can you tell how can i resolve this

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit"/> was causing problem i changed it to name="submitbtn" and solved.. thanks again